# Как с помощью регулярок взять только цифры из текста?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Допустим сть такая строчная переменная: `i = '1234*5678'`, мне нужно взять из нее первую часть цифр до звездочки отдельно, и вторую часть цифр после звездочки.

Comment: Сделайте сплит по всем не цифровым символам и все!)

Comment: @JVic, и получи пару пустых строк по краям.

Comment: о, спасибо!))))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используя метод [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re
print(re.findall('\d+', '1234*5678'))  # ['1234', '5678']
```

Используя метод [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.split), тогда разделение нужно делать от противного – все, кроме чисел:

```
print(re.split('\D+', '1234*5678'))  # ['1234', '5678']
```

Comment: по-моему лучше использовать `'\D+'`, вместо `'[^\d]+'`

Comment: @MaxU, согласен :)